# Data doesn't load properly in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

In meteor when my page loads data my general setup is:

```
var data

Router.route('/userinfo/edit', {
  loadingTemplate: 'Loading',
  subscriptions: function(){
    console.log('And now we wait')
    return Meteor.subscribe('_userinfodb', Meteor.userId())
  },
  action: function(){
    console.log('RonPaulItsHappening.gif')
    data = UserInfoDB.find({userId: Meteor.userId()}).fetch()[0]
    if(typeof data == "undefined"){
      var errorReport = 'User ' + Meteor.userId() + ' failed to retrive data from UserInfoDB, on page ' + Router.current().path + ' on ' + new Date() + '.'
      Meteor.call('generateErrorReport', errorReport)
      this.redirect('/error/data')
    }
    console.log(data)
    this.render('userinfoedit')
  }
})
```

This occasionally works, but is pretty finnicky, and usually leads to data being undefined. However, once you land on /error/data if you hit back, the data will load just fine. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you're asking us to assume a context where this is always "something other than undefined? `data = UserInfoDB.find({userId: Meteor.userId()}).fetch()[0]` ?

Comment: Yes, an entry into UserInfoDB is automatically generated when a new account is registered.

Answer (score 0):

1. `waitOn` the subscription to ensure data is ready before `action` is invoked and that the `loadingTemplate` is shown until then.
2. For security, never, ever, ever pass `Meteor.userId()` to a subscription or method from the client. Just use `this.userId` (publish function) or `Meteor.userId()` (method) on the server side.

Comment: Now action isn't being invoked. New code: http://pastebin.com/8KBDnc0w  Also, I did poorly code the Meteor.userId() parts, I was planning on fixing it before the website went live.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `if (this.ready())` in your `action:` anymore.

Comment: Even after removing it, action still isn't being invoked. Do I need to do this.next() or something?

Comment: Is your publication becoming ready on the server? If so it should work. You might want to look at the network in inspector and see what's going on on the wire.